# Проблема в админской панели Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-admin

В общем решил я значит по практиковатся и запилить админку благодаря которой можно было изменять некоторые параметры сайта но не суть, так вот проблема в том что в админке не отображается именно тот класс который и должен отвечать за изменеия на главной странице. Точнее класс отображается но вот когда я нажимаю add то там ничего не высвечивается[image: вот картинка что бы вам было понятно о чём я говорю]

вот код  от admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Sale
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Sale)

admin.site.register(Question)


class Sale(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['description_text']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['price_text']}),
    ]
```

вот код от models.py

```
class Sale(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)


class Sale(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text
```

вот код от views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

def price(self):
    return self.price_text

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: Почему у вас `class Sale(models.Model):` повторяется два раза?

Comment: @andreymal а это имеет значение ?

Comment: Ну да, вы же создали две разные модели с одинаковым именем, и вторая модель не имеет ни одного поля, и поэтому в админке пусто

Comment: @andreymal так что получается их надо соединить ?

Comment: или переименовывать или импортировать с другим именем, типа from .models import Sale as ModelSale